# Whats wrong with this code? Whenever i try to click the button my application just stops responding? this is a post request code

Tags: java, android, post

Here is the my post request code. please help me debug this one. thanks. i can run my application but it doesnt give out errors.

```
public void ibutton4Click()
    {
           {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("10.0.0.1/cgi-bin/ForwardPress.cgi");
                try {

                  HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                  String line = "";
                  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                  }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
                }
              }
    }
```

Comment: You're executing a long-lasting task on the main UI thread. You have to do these things in the background so the UI keeps functioning in the meanwhile.

Comment: background? like putting it inside an Asynctask?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the exact Android implementation but yes, from first glance that looks exactly like what you want. *AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.*

Answer (score 0):

For more on NetworkOnMainThread error and why is it that way,
1. [Responsive UI in design and interaction](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)
2. [More on the Adroid class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)
3. [Useful SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

**To fetch the data** in a separate thread,

**1.** Write custom `Asynctasks`:
[AsyncTask Dev Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

**OR**

**2.** Use something like AsyncHttpClient:  http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
where you get `onSuccess` and `onFailure` methods to work with the response.

The option *2.* is better if you just want to fetch data without doing anything else, and work on it, or save it. For the same, you need to parse the response first.